# Being asked to login when connecting a Google Sheet to Excel with the Get Data function

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-account

I have created a data input form using Google Forms.
This stores data in a Google Sheet.

But I want to link this Google Sheet to an Excel file in order to do further analysis.

The problem is this:
When I use a Google Sheet on my own Google account, linking it with the "Get Data -> From Web" functionality in Excel is not a problem at all.

However if I do the same with my company Google account (which I would prefer, since this is company data), I get this item as my only return:

[image]

It basically asks for my work-google account login info.
Is there a way around this? Or can I enter the info somewhere?

I've tried searching for solutions for a while, but haven't found anything answering this.

Comment: Can you login with your company account? If the issue is being asked to login every time, I think you should contact with your G Suite Admin, since it looks like a restriction.

Comment: Typing in the  field in my pictore doesn`t do anything. Perhaps contating my admin is the next step, thanks.